# Android String that change every day

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have one string that changes every day because it keeps data from internet. I want to store text every day(on users click) in a list ( or array list), the problem is that when I store it I delete the text of the previous day 
Any solution? 
Thanks

Comment: just don't  `delete the text of the previous day`

Comment: I'd recommend concatenating the Strings together before you save them. That way you can save them under the same key and then keep both. When you fetch them, you can split them again

Comment: Simply **append** the new string, instead of overwriting the old one.

Answer (score 1):

To store string on every day basis you need to store it in `Share dPreferences` or `SQLite`, and you can retrieve it from there whenever you want.

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is `SQLite`. Because using `SQLite` you can easily get string of specific date. But using `SharedPreference`, it is not easy to manage and also `SharedPrefernce` are used for storing less size data.